# Query slow when use count(*) and inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, query-optimization

My query is taking around 5 seconds to run. It returns almost 5000 records.

```
SELECT 
    c.CompanyID, 
    c.CompanyName, 
    psr.PartnerSRFName, 
    psr.PartnerSRLName, 
    be.MonthlyFee, 
    (
        SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM Units
        INNER JOIN Properties ON Units.PropertyID = Properties.PropertyID
        WHERE Properties.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
    ) TotalUnits
FROM Company c
LEFT JOIN Partner_SalesRep_CompanyMap psrcm ON c.CompanyID = psrcm.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN Partner_SalesReps psr ON psrcm.Partner_SalesRepsID = psr.AssignedID
LEFT JOIN Billing_Exemption be ON be.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
WHERE c.LeadSourceCompanyID = 1 AND Active = 1
```

If I remove the `Select Count(*) ...`, it runs very fast, but I need this data. Is there a way to improve this query?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an unique id in table `Units`, like `Units.UnitID?

Comment: Yes, I have the id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexes recommended by Gordon Linoff are a must-have.

Another thing you could to is move the computation from an inlined query to a joined subquery. This might allow the RDBMS to optimize the query, since it is now explicit that there is no need to repeat the computation for each record (only distinct values of `CompanyID` actually make a difference):

```
SELECT 
    c.CompanyID, 
    c.CompanyName, 
    psr.PartnerSRFName, 
    psr.PartnerSRLName, 
    be.MonthlyFee, 
    COALESCE(x.TotalUnits, 0) TotalUnits
FROM Company c
LEFT JOIN Partner_SalesRep_CompanyMap psrcm ON c.CompanyID = psrcm.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN Partner_SalesReps psr ON psrcm.Partner_SalesRepsID = psr.AssignedID
LEFT JOIN Billing_Exemption be ON be.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Properties.CompanyID, COUNT(*) TotalUnits
    FROM Units
    INNER JOIN Properties ON Units.PropertyID = Properties.PropertyID
    GROUP BY Properties.CompanyID
) x ON x.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
WHERE c.LeadSourceCompanyID = 1 AND Active = 1
```

Another option would be to turn merge the subquery with the outer query (by adding more joins to the outer query), turn on aggregation on the entire outer query, and use a unique column in table `Units` or `Properties` to do the count . I am not a big fan of this one, as, usually, the earlier you aggregate the better efficiency you get.

Comment: I am surprised that this would work better than the correlated subquery.  How much faster is this?

Comment: @myTest532myTest532: can you please let us know if the above accepted SQL is giving better performance than the original? I saw that you accepted the answer (thanks!), and I am curious about the results too...

Comment: . . The issue may be that there are very few companies and lots of rows returned by the query.  If this is the case, then the correlated subquery would be running multiple times for each company, and your version would be faster.  That needs to be weighed against the index usage that a correlated subquery allows, but thee are definitely circumstances where this would be faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: thanks for sharing the analyzis and for sportmanship! Yes, I totally agree with your views... That was an interesting question though, although maybe not enough documented.

Answer (score 2):

For this subquery:

```
(Select Count(*)
 From Units u join
      Properties p
      on u.PropertyID = p.PropertyID
 Where p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
) as TotalUnits
```

You want indexes on `properties(companyid, propertyid)` and `units(propertyid)`.

Comment: Isn't it the same query I posted just with index for units and properties tables? It is taking the same time

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 . . .  That is interesting.  Did you already have those indexes?